# Laravel Paypal API single payout

Tags: api, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to integrate the Paypal API to my Laravel project to send payments to users emails automatically from my own Paypal account.

The thing is that there are some "mass payments" packages but that's not what I need, I actually need to send a single payment to one user each time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about package you are using but for single payout or any type of payment you can use PayPalPHP SDK and here is sample code for single Payout :

[Paypal Single Payout PHP](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payouts/CreateSinglePayout.php)

This is PHP Package and you can pull with composer so you can easily use with Laravel Also.

Let me know if have any question.

For document please have a look Paypal Documents API:

[Paypal Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch#payouts_create)